# IIS 7.5 app pool stops on first request to web page

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, html, application-pool

EDIT: I figured this out. I had some troubles loging on to my computer, getting a error message saying something like: The trust relationship between the domains failed. Since I was using this user on the app pool, instead of the ApplicationPoolIdentity user, it didn't work. I switched the the apppool user and then it worked.

I have set up an app pool with asp.net 4.5, and have a web page running on that app pool. When I try to load the page in my browser the app pool stops. As a result I get a 503 status.

I really don't know what is going on.
The app pool .net version is v4.0.30319 and and have pipeline mode Integrated.

Have anyone encoutered this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. I had some troubles loging on to my computer, getting a error message saying something like: The trust relationship between the domains failed. Since I was using this user on the app pool, instead of the ApplicationPoolIdentity user, it didn't work. I switched the the apppool user and then it worked.